# How to implement a configurable singleton?

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns

This question is related to Android but can also be asked in other situations. I need to create a library where singletons are exposed; or I want to ensure only one instance of my classes exists and can be grabbed anywhere in the code without passing references.

But thoses singletons needs some parameters. For instance in Android, a `Context` object is often needed. I must also precise that since I provide a library, I want things to be easy for the user and **I do not have control of the `Application` class** in Android (this class can sometimes be used to manage object instances for a whole app).

One known solution is to do the following:

```
static MySingleton sInstance;
MySingleton.getInstance(Context c) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new MySingleton(c.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}
```

But it is strange since the parameter of `getInstance` is actually only used at the first creation of the singleton.

I could provide a setter to the singleton and asks the developer to correctly set the needed parameters, but some strange situations could arise:

```
// Good usage
MySingleton.getInstance().setContext(context.getApplicationContext());
MySingleton.getInstance().doSomethingThatRequiresContext(); // OK

// Bad usage
MySingleton.getInstance().doSomethingThatRequiresContext(); // Error!
MySingleton.getInstance().setContext(context.getApplicationContext());
```

I could check at the start of each method if the singleton is correctly configured and launch some exceptions in case of a bad state, but the API is less straightforward to use:

```
MySingleton.getInstance().setContext(context.getApplicationContext());

try {
    MySingleton.getInstance().doSomethingThatRequiresContext();
}
catch(BadSingletonConfiguration e) { }
```

Even if I use runtime exceptions, it would be dangerous to use.

Unless I kindly ask the user to manually create the instance and to ensure himself only one instance will exist, I do not see a good solution.

Comment: Maybe use Immutable objects.... Java String is implemented to be Immutable.

Comment: Please note that every single one of the examples below has a memory leak if the singleton is referenced inside a thread. You have to use WeakReference to store a context, otherwise you're context won't be GC'd when it should be otherwise.

Comment: If you write about the context, usually a getApplicationContext() is done to have a context that encompass the whole activity lifecycle, so it is not GC'ed while the app is live. I can modify the examples if you like.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a createInstance method that takes a Context and a getInstance that will return null or throw some meaningful exception if they call getInstance before create instance. Maybe throw a RuntimeException stating that createInstance must be called first.

Also, createInstance will just return the already created instance if it has already been called. Here is a code sample of what I'm thinking:

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private static MySingleton INSTANCE;
    private final Context context;

    public static MySingleton createInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(INSTANCE == null)
        {
            INSTANCE = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance()
    {
        if(INSTANCE == null)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("You must call createInstance first");
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void doSomethingThatRequiresContext()
    {
        context.doSomething();
    }

    private MySingleton(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is very similar to my last example. Exceptions are more centralised to only one method, though.

Comment: The user has to either pass the dependencies in the constructor, which we can't allow access to, or in each method call. The createInstance method is kind of like the constructor here, they have to construct your Object somewhere. I think it would be pretty easy to tell that you need to call createInstance if you accidentally call getInstance first because of the Exception.

Comment: This is pretty much the cleanest option available to you, but store Context references with 'WeakReference' else you will run into issues with memory leak generation when the garbage collector can't run. This will happen with 'any' kind of background processing.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this instead:

```
  MySingleton.getInstance().doSomethingThatRequiresContext(context);
```

But generally it is better to use dependency injection approach instead of using manually created singletons. You may want to look at [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/).

Comment: Not possible since the context object is not available everywhere, and other methods would require it. Dagger would have sense if I control the main app, but it is not the case, I only provide a library.

Comment: I'm having a hard time to came up with an example when Context can't be obtained.

Comment: You're right, but I want to generalize my question with other possible configuration objects, not only context. Anyway, if all my methods needs a context instance and if I have to pass it to each method, we start to move from OOP to a more procedural style where you cannot encapsulate the state of the object :-)

Comment: Perhaps. But in case of Context, it is not state, but link to an environment and saving it in an instance field is prone to various memory and resource leaks.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to return an instance from a static `init` method, and have all the methods on the returned instance.

```
MyInstance instance = MyLibrary.init(context, and, whatever, else);
instance.doSomethingThatRequiresContext();
```

The order of the calls *cannot be reversed* now.

Then all you would potentially need to guard against is calling `init` twice. Which you could do either with runtime exception, or return the previous instance, personally I would Runtime if `init` is called twice.

> I want to ensure only one instance of my classes exists and can be grabbed anywhere in the code without passing references.

Provide a `getInstance` that is valid only after a call to `init`

```
//MyLibrary.getInstance() would throw before init
MyInstance instance1 = MyLibrary.init(context, and, whatever, else);
MyInstance instance2 = MyLibrary.getInstance();
assertSame(instance1, instance2);
```

Note that although only subtly different to your original, by separating the responsibilities of allocation and singleton management in to `MyLibrary`, at least *only* the `init` and `getInstance` methods need to check that init has been called or not. None of the methods on `MyInstance` need to worry.

> Even if I use runtime exceptions, it would be dangerous to use.

I don't think you can't solve this problem without them. It's more dangerous to not throw when something is seriously wrong, like the user has not initialized. Just add a good error message to back up your documentation.

Full listing:

```
public final class MyInstance {

    private final Context context;

    MyInstance(Context context, and, whatever, else) {
        //package private, can't be directly instantiated by library user
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void doSomethingThatRequiresContext() {
      //no special checks required
    }

    //add other methods, this is just a normal class
}

public static class MyLibrary {

    private static Object lockObj = new Object();

    private static MyInstance myInstance;

    public static MyInstance init(context, and, whatever, else) { 
        synchronized(lockObj) {
            if (myInstance != null)
                throw new RuntimeException("Please do not call init more than once");
            myInstance = new MyInstance(context, and, whatever, else);
            return myInstance;
        }
    }

    public static MyInstance getInstance() {
        synchronized(lockObj) {
            if (myInstance == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("Please call init before getInstance");
            return myInstance;
        }
    }

}
```